# Fermat point proof with complex numbers.

Tags: geometry

Can the Fermat point be proved with complex numbers ? I have seen some proofs with vectors but they have taken it to subtend an angle 120° with the vertices. Can it be proved without any such assumption i tried to circumscribe a circle but no result . Also in a place i read that there are cases for an angle of triangle ≤120° and ≥120° .in one proof can both be embedded.
I am looking for a proof with geometric property of complex numbers be used.
What is the minimum sum of vertices from Fermat point is there any expression?
I encountered a question |z–a|+|z–b|+|z-c| minimize it.
This is Fermat point . All are complex variables. So i wanted a solution via complex numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "proving the Fermat point". A search online gives [this proof](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/NapoleonLeo.shtml).

Comment: Thanks @Toby Mak  ,.         but without taking the cube root of unity can it be proved because we know Fermat point subtend angle of 120° after which we are able to make the assumption

Comment: I mean to get the location of Fermat point of a triangle.i have edited the question.

Comment: I don't think you can do so without using the assumption of $120º$. Just because a problem is in complex geometry, does not mean complex geometry is the best way to proceed. There are proofs of this that do not involve pure geometry (say using vectors) if you're interested in them.

Comment: Ok.   thanks for advice..   you have said right .Mathematics is a mixture of many things . we can transform the complex points to analytical geometry and prove it with  pure geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $z=x+iy$, $a=x_1+iy_1$, $b=x_2+iy_2$, $c=x_3+iy_3$.
Then the value to minimize is:
$$
\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}.\tag1
$$
To find the critical point differentiate the expression over $x$ and $y$ to obtain:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{x-x_1}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}}+\frac{x-x_2}{\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}}
+\frac{x-x_3}{\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}}=0\\
\frac{y-y_1}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}}+\frac{y-y_2}{\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}}
+\frac{y-y_3}{\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}}=0
\end{cases}\tag2$$
Multiplying the lower line by $i$ and adding with the upper line one obtains the equation:
$$
z_1+z_2+z_3=0,\text{ with } |z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1.\tag3
$$
It should not be difficult  to demonstrate that the solutions $\{z_1,z_2,z_3\}$ to equation (3) form an equilateral triangle in the complex plane.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. @user.